# Crystal Reports Prevent global variables from resetting on new page

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there any way to prevent the resetting of variables on a new page?

In GH2 I initialize the following variable:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
    Global NumberVar RCountDaysInDenominator :=  0;
```

In GF3:

```
EvaluateAfter ({@IsEndExamPopulated});
    if {@IsEndExamPopulated} = True 
then 
NumberVar RCountDaysInDenominator :=          NumberVar  RCountDaysInDenominator + 1
else 
NumberVar RCountDaysInDenominator := NumberVar  RCountDaysInDenominator + 0;
```

I didn't realize that when a single GF3 spans many pages, these variables reset.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It shouldn't be the issue unless your group 2 changes...what is the status when next group gf3 starts in single page

Comment: Please clarify "when group 2 changes"? 
It's printed like this
'code'
    GH2 Technician Name (initialize Day Counter variable here)
    GF3 Day 1 (increment Day Counter variable)
    GF3 Day 2 (increment Day Counter variable)
    GF3 Day 3 (increment Day Counter variable)
    GF3 Day 4 (increment Day Counter variable)
    GF3 Day 5 (increment Day Counter variable)
    GF2 Calcululate stats using the Day Counter variable as a denominator

For some reason the Day Counter variable resets to 0 when the GF3 spans numerous pages

Comment: @jch Just created a test sample. Initialized a var in GH2, incremented in GF3, used it in GF2, made GF3 large enough to span more than two pages as you described. And the var does NOT reset. Make sure you are not resetting the var anywhere else except GH2.